# Multi Tenancy and Single Tenancy with a single service

Tags: apache-kafka, multi-tenant

I'm building something like a webhook provider for different usecases. People will use my webhook url and add them to third-party services where the services can call my webhook to denote an event.

I can have multiple clients where some clients are comfortable with a multi-tenant setup but some clients need complete isolation and needs to be single tenant [ everything from API servers to Databases to Kafka ]

The architecture I'm thinking of right now

1. There will be one deployment which can handle all clients who are fine with a multi-tenant setup. Each client will have a subdomain and the sub-domain will be mapped to a secret which will be used for signing the payload from the webhook initiator. I can use the subdomain to fetch secrets from Redis and validate payload.
2. For every client who needs single tenancy, I will create a separate deployment when required and create a new DNS entry to map the subdomain to the new IP. Here, I'll store the secret in environment variable since there's only one tenant. They will also have their own database.

I have two questions

1. Is this the right approach for such a setup?
2. I also need to have something like kafka to actually process the message since I don't want to rely on the webhooks retry policy and I want to make sure no messges are lost from my end. There are also different actions I want to perform per message and I can use kafka consumer groups. Do I create separate topics for each customer who needs isolation? If that's the case, it feels like a big overhead given that consumer groups will have to be deployed separately for each topic and each customer which is going to be expensive.